# sscanf is not writing properly

Tags: c, scanf

I am learning C, and there is something that I can't figure out about sscanf. When printing to a buffer, there isn't any data being written, and they always fail with -1. If you see the second printf statement, I can clearly view my data on screen so I know it's right, but for some reason as a pointer nothing is there.

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
char *v = (char*)&int_value;
int i;
for(i=0;i<sizeof(unsigned int);i++)
{
    printf("sscanf success: %d ", sscanf(&v[i], "%02x", &buffer[pos+i]));
    printf("%02x\n", v[i]);
}
```

Thanks, I am just doing byte by byte now `buffer[pos+i] = v[i];`

Comment: how is `buffer` defined? also `&v[i]` appears to be doing the wrong thing, it access `v`'s pointer at position `i` then taking the pointer to that pointer at that position, why?

Comment: The function `sscanf` expects an actual string as the first argument.

Comment: `buffer` is a char *. But if I do use a real string like, `sscanf("0f", "%02x", &buffer[pos+i])` then it will write just fine. What function should I be using instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that the int value was somehow converted to ascii by the type cast, but it is not so the sscanf will fail. sscanf needs a valid C string to operate on e.g. `char* p = "02";` but when you type cast the int you get actual byte representation of the number - there could be for instance a 0 in the middle terminating the string.

E.g. if your int value is 8 it would look something like this in memory: 00 00 10 00 (or 00h 08h in hex - exactly how it looks depends on your architecture).

Comment: I am trying to do decimal to little endian hex and save to the buffer. How would I best accomplish this?

Comment: you are already printing out the hex values with your printf in a certain order, is your OS little or big endian? If it is in little endian then it is just a matter of copying to the buffer byte by byte. if not you can use a union e.g. `typedef union { unsigned int n; unsigned char b[4]; } uu` then just swap bytes

Comment: Yes it does work, but I am not sure how to get the data into the buffer. Thanks for your help, also the OS is little endian

Comment: Thanks... Sometimes coding at late night is a bad thing :) I am just copying the data directly in there and works fine now, but did learn something about `sscanf` in the process.